# Need to justify $\int_{n}^{S_{n}}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x} } \approx \frac{S_{n}-n}{\sqrt{n}}$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems

This is the text of the problem: Let $(X_{j})_{j\geq 1}$ be i.i.d. nonnegative with $E\{X_{1}\}=1$ and $\sigma_{X_{1}}^{2}=\sigma^{2} \in (0, \infty)$, and let $S_{n}=\sum_{j=1}^{n}X_{j}$. Show that $\frac{2}{\sigma}(\sqrt{S_{n}}-\sqrt{n})\to^{\mathcal{D}}Z$, with $\mathcal{L}(Z)=N(0,1)$.

I was given the following hint: Notice that $(2\sqrt{x})^{\prime} = x^{-1/2}$. So, $2(\sqrt{S_{n}}-\sqrt{n})=\int_{n}^{S_{n}}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}$. Now, $\frac{S_{n}-n}{\sqrt{n}} \to^{\mathcal{D}} N(0,1)$ by the Central Limit Theorem. So, show that $\int_{n}^{S_{n}}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}} \approx \frac{S_{n}-n}{\sqrt{n}}$.

So, this is what I tried to do: $|\int_{n}^{S_{n}}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}-\frac{S_{n}-n}{\sqrt{n}}|=|\int_{n}^{S_{n}}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)dx|=2 \sqrt{S_{n}}-\sqrt{n}-\frac{S_{n}}{\sqrt{n}}$, and eventually what I would like to do is show that this goes to $0$ as $n$ gets large. However, I am having trouble doing that. Please help!

Comment: I made some manipulations and I got this
$ \frac{2}{\sigma}(\sqrt{S_{n}}-\sqrt{n}) = \frac{2\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt(S_n)+\sqrt(n)}\cdot \frac{S_n -n}{\sigma \sqrt(n)}$

Note that the term $\frac{2\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt(S_n)+\sqrt(n)}$ intuitively goes to one, since the on average the $X_i$'s are 1, then $S_n$ is on average $n$. If you could prove that this term goes to 1 in probability then your result follows by http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky's_theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a comment, but now I think I got a answer.
After some manipulations you can get this

$$\frac{2}{\sigma}(\sqrt{S_{n}}-\sqrt{n}) = \frac{2\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{S_n}+\sqrt{n}}\cdot \frac{S_n -n}{\sigma \sqrt{n}}$$

But, as I said intuitively $\frac{2\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{S_n}+\sqrt{n}}$ goes to 1 because $X_i$ is one on average and then $S_n$ is $n$ on average.

Now, the Law of Large Numbers tells us that $$ \frac{S_n}{n} \rightarrow 1 \text{ a.s}$$. This implies that $$ \frac{2\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{S_n}+\sqrt{n}} \rightarrow 1 \text{ a.s}$$ 
and by [Slutsky's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky%27s_theorem) you have your result once $ \frac{S_n -n}{\sigma \sqrt{n}} \rightarrow \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ by the Central Limit Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*: By [mean value theorem for integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorems_for_integration), we have

$$\int_n^{S_n}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}=\frac{S_n-n}{\sqrt{t}}$$

for some $t$ between $n$ and $S_n.$